# VBA editor in excel is inaccessible

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2021

I am unable to do anything in VBA editor in office, it just shows few big letters and nothing else, it´s impossible to reach settings or anything else, also it´s in french, don´t know why.
[image]

I already reinstall whole Office, but nothing has changed. I also tried to delete register data.

Comment: How do you bring that window up? How do you know it's in French? What happens when you uncollapse whatever that is collapsed on the left side of that window?

Comment: In caption on the top is written: "Microsoft Visual Basic pour Applications", and one and only shortcut which works was for printing menu, which was also in french. And all the window is unresponsive to anything

Comment: What happens when you hit the maximise button on that window?
Also make sure you don't have a 2nd monitor in use - sounds weird I know, but it does sometimes have a weird effect

Comment: It just maximaze with no effect, and when i roll it through both monitors, it´s possible to read word "fichier" which goes for "file" in english

Comment: So it's super zoomed. What you see is the top left of the IDE's menu bar.

Comment: That was what I thought, but I can´t find any way to zoom out, without going through panel menu, which i can´t reach. So far I haven´t found any shortcut

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1316144/52365?

Comment: Unfortunately didn´t work, maybe because I can modify like that only Excel application, but these changes didn´t go through VBA module, which is not as an application itself

Comment: The VBA Settings are stored in registry under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1 No idea if that helps, but you could give it a try: Exit Excel/VBA, open RegEdit, go to this branch, Save it (File->Export) and then delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but fortunately this problem vanished after few months with one update