# Excel VBA editor does not function, it just says "FILE"

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have run into a problem with excel VBA. Every time i try to open the VBA editor, it will open in a window that just says "FILE". I cannot click anything, write anything or zoom.

Have anybody else found a solution to this problem?
Screenshot is shown below.

[image]

Comment: What Office version do you use? Was it ever working as it should? It seems that VBA is not installed. I can see on the picture top left corner "Application Edition Mappe2"? What does it mean?

Comment: Microsoft 365, just got a new PC from work, so this is the first time i've tried to use VBA on this machine. Mappe2 means folder 2.

Comment: First ask your company IT for help.

Comment: Did you try pressing ALT+F11 to access to editor?

Comment: Yes i tried that too.

Comment: Is that the whole "screenshot" ? Ity looks cropped to me.

Comment: Only thing cropped is the process bar at the buttom. 
The picture shows the entire window as i see it.

Comment: More of the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76279792/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77536999/11683

Answer (score 1):

It looks like very zoomed top left corner:

[image]

It can be more OS problem not Excel. In Windows, try to check/set to 100% the size of text, apps, and other items in display settings.

Comment: I have tried that, i does not work unfortunatly...
the wierd thing is all other apps are not zoomed in.

Comment: Ask IT department for help. It can be caused by video driver or by anything else.

Comment: I will try that, maybe that is the only answer.