VBA editor in Excel - not accessible and won't respond
When I try to open the VBA editor in Excel (365), the window opens up and no button is clickable, there is just a huge font text in the middle (not readable) - it seems like the text is in Spanish or French.
I wrote to the Microsoft support team and they couldn't help me (told me to ask here). There is nothing online on this bug, Chat GPT has no answers also.
I tried re-installing Excel.
Can someone give me  a lead on this?


I met a question about such issue here but have no information about the resolution. Try to clamp down CTRL and scroll the wheel.

Double-click on window's title bar. It's the purely Microsoft issue not Stack overflow.

Very similar issue raised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500295 but no solution posted. Maybe uninstall/reinstall?

You've already reinstalled Excel. Does the problem also occur in other VBA windows? (from Word, PowerPoint ...) In that case you might have to reinstall the complete Office package, and maybe clean the registry after uninstalling.

Try this. 1. Close Excel. 2. Open the Registry Editor (press Win + R, type regedit, and press Enter). 3. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common. 4. Delete the entire Common key. CAREFUL: Do not delete anything else. 5. Close Registry Editor 6. Restart Excel and try to open the VBA editor.
