# Excel VBA manager is zoomed in, see picture! how do i fix it?

Tags: excel, vba

When i open excel VBA, its zoomed in so far the top of the bar that says FILE is so large it takes up the entire screen. I have had this problem for over a week now and i cannot find a solution to the problem. Our IT department also have not been able to find a solution. I am hoping someone here might have a solution for this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using multiple monitors?

Comment: No just one at the moment, but the problem is the same when using a single monitor as using multiple monitors.

Comment: I only asked because some things can only be reset in the VBA IDE if on your primary monitor. However, I'll go have a look through my notes to see if I worked out how to fix it (I had this same problem years ago but can't remember what the solution was)

Comment: That would be perfect, i would deeply appreciate it!

Comment: Previous instance of the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76279792/11683

Comment: I see, in that instance there was no answer that worked though.

Comment: Another (unanswered) version of the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/77500295/7446760

Comment: Sorry I can't try these as I can't reproduce the problem but could you try right-click on the VBA taskbar icon while holding down the left-shift key. Choose "Restore" from the context menu and see if that helps?

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work either..